# Bar Chart Labels stuck in top left corner

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make simple chart right now importing data from a CSV. Everything on the chart is working great except for the labels. In element inspect I can see that they are being appended and that their x and y coordinates are even correct, but for some reason they are all trapped in the top left corner in the SVG itself.

I have tried changing the x placement function at first because I thought it just wasn't giving the labels a x position, but upon further inspection the labels have the correct metadata.

```
//Graph Dimensions
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
   width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
   height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//Set Ranges
var x_scale = d3.scaleBand()
      .range([0, width])
      .padding(0.1);
var y_scale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height, 0]);

//Create SVG object
var svg = d3.select('#chart')
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", 
     "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Retrieve data
d3.csv('sales.csv').then(function(data){

//Set domains based on data
x_scale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.month; }));
y_scale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.sales; })]);

//Create bars
svg.selectAll("rect")
   .data(data)
   .enter().append("rect")
   .attr("class", "bar")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return x_scale(d.month); })
   .attr("width", x_scale.bandwidth())
   .attr("y", function(d) { return y_scale(d.sales); })
   .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y_scale(d.sales); });

//Create labels
svg.selectAll('text')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('text')
  .attr('class', 'label')
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x_scale(d.month); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y_scale(d.sales); })
  .attr( 'font-size', 14 )
  .attr( 'fill', '#555555' )
  .attr( 'text-anchor', 'middle' );

//Add Axes
svg.append("g") //X Axis
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(d3.axisBottom(x_scale));

svg.append("g") //Y Axis
   .call(d3.axisLeft(y_scale));
})
```

The only thing im looking for is the labels actually appearing. I can change their location later if needed.

Comment: You may need to actually give the labels text - you have labels but they don't contain any text to display which could be why they are in the top left.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I feel real stupid lol.

Comment: Easy to miss: why should a lack of text change the x,y properties? I've missed it lots of times.